# Graph Control for Windows Universal Apps

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, uwp, windows-10-universal

I want to have an undirected graph, with text as nodes, in a Windows Universal App. Unfortunately, many existing toolkits either cater to graphing charts, or have graph tools, but are not compatible with Windows Universal Apps. (They tend to be compatible to an older variant of .NET, WPF, WinForms, etc.)

Visually, I'm talking about something here, with nodes and edges: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(abstract_data_type)

Are there any toolkits out there that work with UWP that support a graph, ideally with examples?

Answer (score 0):

The https://github.com/MyToolkit/MyToolkit may you need.

And the https://github.com/zmtzawqlp/UWP-master can use the DataGrid.

And https://github.com/deepwaterdiver/O365-UWP-Microsoft-Graph-Connect-master.

And you can use Win2D,if you need the  custom graph.

Comment: I'm sorry if I was unclear, but I want a graph, with nodes, vertices and lines connecting them, to visualize on a Windows Universal App.

The first link has a graph-like structure, but that seems to only keep track of children and changes in data. I can't seem to find any suggestion that it actually shows a graph. Also, Microsoft Graph connects APIs together. I wish it showed a graph as the name suggests, haha!

Does that help?

Comment: I'm sorry for my misunderstanding.If you want to draw the graph 
and I know  [WinRT XAML Toolkit](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/) or [TelerikRadControls for Windows](http://www.telerik.com/windows-universal-ui).WinRT XAML Toolkit is free.You can use Nuget :WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.DataVisualization.UWP ![](http://www.uwphub.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/image001.png). `xmlns:Charting=”using:WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting”` The pie chart, bar charts, line chart.And http://www.drjukka.com/blog/wordpress/?p=193

Comment: None of these toolkits provide a a way to make a graph in Universal Windows app. They make charts. I want to have a graph, undirected, with nodes and edges/lines connecting the nodes. A quick visual of what it should be is from wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(abstract_data_type)

Comment: I'm sorry and I can't help you.I think you can make a toolkit use Win2D.